# Get UTC process start time in Linux

Tags: linux, process, ps, timestamps

This `ps` command gives timezone-specific time:

```
$ date
Mon Mar 22 19:17:54 MSK 2021

$ ps -eo pid,cmd,lstart
  PID CMD                                          STARTED
    1 /init                       Mon Mar 22 19:13:33 2021
    6 /init                       Mon Mar 22 19:13:33 2021
    7 /init                       Mon Mar 22 19:13:33 2021
    8 -bash                       Mon Mar 22 19:13:33 2021
   33 ps -eo pid,cmd,lstart       Mon Mar 22 19:17:56 2021
o2genum@DESKTOP-TMJIEPG:~$
```

What is the simplest way to get the process start time in UTC?

Comment: Similar:  [Process start time with time zone](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/363193)

Comment: Also: [ps output with iso date format?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/401785)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just:

```
TZ=UTC0 ps -eo pid,cmd,lstart
```

The `TZ` variable is the one that specifies the timezone. With `UTC0` we define one called `UTC` with a constant 0 offset from Universal  Time (how we call it doesn't matter here though as `ps` doesn't care about its name; `TZ=FOO0` would work the same).